# Ответ на пожелание доброго дня

Tags: лексика, этикет

*Подскажите приятное ответное пожелание в дореволюционной форме. Что-нибудь интересное в чеховском стиле...*

Answer (score 1):

-И Вам не хворать
-Благодарствую серде**ш**но
-Вам того же пожелаю
-Премного благодарен
-Вас тоже рад я видеть
Небольшой экспромт, думаю, Вам стоит обратиться к книгам, написанным в ту чудесную эпоху, там вы и отыщите ответ(ы).